# jquery data is not parsing value html5 data custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have the following HTML tags generated by back end

```
<select name="brand" class="form-control">
    <option value="1" data-info="[{id=1, name=detail#1}, {id=2, name=detail#2}, {id=3, name=detail#3}]">brand#1</option>
    <option value="2" data-info="[{id=3, name=detail#3}, {id=4, name=detail#4}, {id=5, name=detail#5}]">brand#2</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to access data-info value when user change option, so i try this code

```
$('#brand').on('change', function(){
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var info = optionSelected.data("info")

    console.log(typeof info)
})
```

But when i get typeof info i get a string, and i need and object.

If i try JSON.parse(info) i get *SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data*

I understand this error could be for two reasons info is already parsed or it is not valid json.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The JSON that you have is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's JSON handler only translates valid JSON. The JSON you have in there is not valid. Specifically, it's missing the necessary quotes and you're using `=` rather than `:`. It should read something like:

```
<option value="1" data-info='[{"id":1, "name":"detail#1"}, {"id":2, "name":"detail#2"}, {"id":3, "name":"detail#3"}]'>brand#1</option>
```

For reference, [the JSON spec](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: you are right @Ouroborus, i just fixed the error in backend, now is rendering valid json as you suggest and i am getting objects